# Incorrect gdb configurations for vscode?

Tags: c, debugging, linker-errors, vscode-debugger

I have some c files, organized like so:

```
└── src
    ├── app.out
    ├── Makefile
    ├── main.c
    ├── test.c
    └── test.h
```

The files compile just fine, when I build them with `make`.
I am developing in VSCode and use the C/C++ debugger extension.
However, I can't get the debugger to work properly. Earlier I had some problems that the debugger didn't work, because of some linking problems? (undefined_reference problems).
I did some more experimenting with the launch.json file to configure the debugger, but I just can't get it to work. Now the debugger just exits, and does not halt on any breakpoint.

```
This is my config:
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I configure the debugger that it just works normally, aka holding on bp's and not having any linking problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I simply forgot to generate the debug symbols with `-g` in the Makefile.